# open mail sending prompt in new tab using mailto:

Tags: html, email

I am using below code to send mail from html page.

```
<a href="mailto:myMail@domain.com" target="_blank"><input id="commentButton" name="Comment" type="button" value="Add Comment"></a>
```

Launch application Mail prompt is getting opened in the same browser tab.

I want to open it in the new tab.

Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't understand this. How is the mail application opening in the browser? It's a separate application?

Comment: Not mail application. i am talking about launch application box which gives options to select mail client